# Exclude an Android/data folder from cache cleanup

Tags: file-management, 8.1-oreo, cache, file-permissions

I have a game which downloads all of it's data and contents in a folder in Android/data . The size is over 400MB and device is not rooted. Every time I do a cache and junk cleanup, All files of this game in Android/data get deleted. Is there an option or trick or even an app to exclude a folder from getting scanned and deleted by cleanup apps? Is the problem related to permissions of folder?

Comment: The best thing would be to use a cleanup app which permits excluding a file or a folder. Which cleanup app do you use?

Comment: @Firelord I'm using default cleaner. Xiaomi cleaner.

Comment: Try reporting this to the development team responsible for handling bug's.. They should implement a solution permanently... I'm fairly sure it's a simple line of code added to the manifest... Something along the lines of `excludeFromCacheCleaners=true` I can't remember it exactly... I'm sure they'd like to know your issue, I've had great response's simply using the feedback option on the Google Play Store ( Review )

Comment: @Zillinium I have reported this to developers on both Google play store and In-game feedback system many times since 1year ago. They never fixed it. However I found an app "clean master lite" Wich let you to exclude an app. Hope it helps to others.

Comment: Slack dev team... It's a simple fix that could benefit everyone using the app.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an Android built-in feature to exclude a folder from scan. Hiding a folder may be useful but in this case the folder will be created again. So using an app called [Clean master lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.lite) you can exclude an app from scans. Go to Settings->ignorelist